# Verify Spring Configuration without full start up

Tags: spring, configuration

I have a large spring project, using xml configuration.  I'm looking for a quick way to verify changes to the xml configuration.

I can load the whole project locally - the problem is this takes more than 5 minutes, loads a huge amount of data.

My XML editor catches XML formatting errors.

I'm looking for something intermediate - to catch obvious problems like references to beans that aren't defined, or calling constructors with the wrong arguments.  Is there a quick way to do this, without having to actually invoke all the constructors and bring up the whole environment?

I'm building with Maven and editing with Eclipse, although my question isn't specific to either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beanoh :

http://beanoh.org/overview.html#Verify

this project does exactly what I'm looking for.  Verify obvious problems with spring config, but without the overhead of initializing everything.

Comment: actually it does appear to be initializing everything, just behind the scenes.  Bad.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already use Eclipse, you could try [Spring Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.org/sts) (comes either standalone or as an add-on). It's essentially Eclipse with extra Spring-specific features, like Beans Validator. I'm not sure how thorough the validation is, but it should catch most configuration problems.

It's maintained by SpringSource so its integration with Spring "just works" and it's guaranteed not be more or less in sync with Spring Framework's release cycle.

Comment: definitely useful, although STS does seem to be a memory hog, and 'validate' on my spring config file didnt' catch something obvious like type in bean name

Comment: oops - meant *typo in bean name

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Spring testing support to integration test](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing) your Spring configuration. However if the loading of the context is taking 5 mins, then the tests will also take the same amount of time. Spring does cache the context so if you have multiple tests using the same set of Spring contexts, then once cached the tests should be very quick.

I can suggest a few ways to more efficiently test your configuration:

1. Organize your project in modules, with each module being responsible for its own Spring configuration - this way, each module can be independently developed and tested.
2. If you have a modular structure, the testing can be more localized by mocking out the dependent modules, again this is for speed.